# 4x4 Matrix Keypad code in C

Tags: rpi.gpio

i am having a very hard time finding a purely C program for the Raspberry Pi and the 4x4 membrane matrix keypad. i can find python, c#, stamp, c++ and a couple java. however, C is completely missing from my 1/2 day's worth of google'ing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Seems you have to migrate a running program to C by yourself? Main programming language on raspberry pi is `python`.

Comment: i've wanted to learn C for a very long time. it'll be good practice and i'll try that. i did check out Python. i know it's a very capable language.  but, i'd much rather "code to the metal". also, for me personally choosing Python over C is like choosing Visual Basic over C# for asp.net. it looks like a dirty tinker toy, relatively speaking. i'm just surprised because i have been able to find everything i've needed. it's just this one keypad. once i get my program working i'll answer my own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 4

char pressedKey = '\0';
int rowPins[ROWS] = {1, 4, 5, 6};
int colPins[COLS] = {12, 3, 2, 0};

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
   {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
   {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
   {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
   {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

void init_keypad()
{
   for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
   {
      pinMode(colPins[c], OUTPUT);   
      digitalWrite(colPins[c], HIGH);
   }

   for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
   {
      pinMode(rowPins[0], INPUT);   
      pullUpDnControl(rowPins[r], PUD_UP);
   }
}

int findLowRow()
{
   for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
   {
      if (digitalRead(rowPins[r]) == LOW)
         return r;
   }

   return -1;
}

char get_key()
{
   int rowIndex;

   for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
   {
      digitalWrite(colPins[c], LOW);

      rowIndex = findLowRow();
      if (rowIndex > -1)
      {
         if (!pressedKey)
            pressedKey = keys[rowIndex][c];
         return pressedKey;
      }

      digitalWrite(colPins[c], HIGH);
   }

   pressedKey = '\0';

   return pressedKey;
}

int main(void) 
{
   wiringPiSetup();

   init_keypad();

   while(1)
   {
      char x = get_key();

      if (x)
         printf("pressed: %c\n", x);
      else
         printf("no key pressed\n");

      delay(250);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. it just prints pressed: 1 all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Please note it should be

```
pullUpDnControl(rowPins[r], PUD_UP);
```

in the place of

```
digitalWrite(rowPins[r], PUD_UP);
```

Sorry for submitting as Answer as I'm currently LOW on reputation for adding Comments.

Comment: It is indeed an answer. But you should refer to the **answer** from *Mike Kangas* and explain what's wrong with `digitalWrite` and better with `pullUpControl`.